# What is the average size of a move in kilobytes

Tags: lichess

I have a slow connection and I always face connection problems when playing bullet games. My lag (according to lichess) averages 400 milliseconds. However, when I ping Google's IP address 8.8.8.8 it shows a lag of 245 milliseconds.

So why do these two numbers differ? Are chess moves larger in size than what is needed to ping an IP address?

Comment: Not an expert in this topic, but I believe this time has nothing to do with the size of data you sent, but rather with the distance of the server. Perhaps google's server is just closer to you than lichess's. Also I believe this is not really a chess question.

Comment: @user1583209 Well, how many chess questions are there on this site anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move itself is small (depending if the Chess-software is sending only the move or additional data (e.g. a FEN of the position)) this is sginificantly less than 150 bytes.

Depending on how moves are transfered one moves takes about 500 to 800 bytes. You should check the size of the package sent by your ping: If you ping 8.8.8.8. you should get something like

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=60 time=12.638 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=12.814 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=15.309 ms
```

The lag might change during daytime or even seconds depending on the load or setup of your provider.

More important seems to me that the ping to 8.8.8.8 lags with you for 245ms - this is way too much (I e.g. get 12ms). So probably your provider is too slow.